# How to write non parameterized function that returns table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
create or replace function demowhile_()
    returns table (id integer,name varchar(50))
        language 'plpgsql'
       as $$

    declare id integer;
    declare name varchar(50);

    begin
    CREATE temporary TABLE demo_(id integer,name varchar(50));
    CREATE temporary TABLE temp_ (id integer);
        insert into temp_ (select id from demo);

            while (select count(*) from temp_) <> 0
            loop
                id = (select top(1) id from temp_);
                name = (select name from demo where id = id);
                insert into demo_ values (id,name);

                delete from temp_ where id = id;

                end loop;

                return query select id,name from demo;
                end;
                $$;
```

****while executing it is giving error like ****

```
select * from demowhile();

**ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: insert into temp_ (select id,name from demo)
                                  ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  insert into temp_ (select id,name from demo)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function demowhile() line 9 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42702**
```

Comment: just rename your variable `id = (select top(1) id from temp_);` to for example `_id` on all places where you actually want to use it

Comment: `select top(1)` is invalid for Postgres to begin with

Comment: The whole approach seems unnecessarily complicated. As far as I can tell this could be done with one simple SQL statement. No loops, not "top", not PL/pgSQL - especially because at the end you just return the contents of the `demo` table that wasn't changed by the inefficient and slow row-by-row processing in the loop. What is the real problem are you trying to solve with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`demowhile_() returns table (id integer,name varchar(50)` is basically the same thing as `demowhile_(out id integer, out name varchar(50)) returns setof record`

The `id` output column can be referenced directly from within the function. You've then also created a function variable named `id`. So when you assign a value to `id`, are you assigning to the output parameter or the declared variable? PG doesn't know, so you get that error.

And of course the simple solution is to give each a unique name.